# Populate label from single field in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, database-connection

I have a column in a table that contains a message and I want this message to be displayed in a label. Here is my code which currently doesn't populate the label.

```
Protected conString As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sqldirectory")
Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(conString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select message from [database].[dbo].[table]")
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Try
        cnn.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        lblMsg.Text = dr(0).ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        dr = Nothing
    Finally
        cnn.Close()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after playing around, I came up with this which works

```
Protected conString As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sqldirectory")
Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(conString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select message from [database].[dbo].[table]", cnn)
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim msg As String
Try
    cnn.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    While dr.Read()
        msg = dr("message")
        lblMsg.Text = msg
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    dr = Nothing
Finally
    cnn.Close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this by accident whilst searching for something else. There is an easier way to do this.

I would be tempted to create some common app_code to do this. Create your app_code folder in your project and and a common.vb file with the following code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Namespace GetDBResult
Public Class DB
    Public Shared Function GetRecord(sql As String) As String
        Dim result As String
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YourConnectionString").ToString)
        connection.Open()

        Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

        Try
            If command.ExecuteScalar IsNot System.DBNull.Value Then
                result = command.ExecuteScalar
            Else
                result = ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex

        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try

        Return result
    End Function
    End Class
    End Namespace
```

From there you will be able to call the function from any vb code, making it very easy to get a field from a database to assign it to a label. As follows:

```
    Dim sql as string = "your sql query which should return one row and column"
    label1.text = DB.GetRecord(sql)
```

Saves a lot of re-typing.

Oh, remember to import your code in any vb you wish to use your app_code

```
    Imports GetDBResult
```

Many thanks,
Neil